# Matrix Multiplication Integer Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, diophantine-equations

Given a matrix multiplication and a vector addition. (A,b has rational entries)

$$Ax+b$$

how do i get an $x$ for that $Ax+b$ is integer or show that there is not such a solution?
$x$ has no restrictions.

**EDIT**
I am currently trying to find solutions for a reduced problem:

$$Ax$$

you can then set x_i to the common denominator of the column a_i and has a solution.

a) Can you calculate all possible solutions?

b) If you demand A*x >= 0 is there still possible to construct one solution?

Comment: $x = -A^{-1}b$, then $Ax+b $ is a vector of zeros given that $A$ is invertible and $A$ and $b$ are of appropriate size.

Comment: yes but i am more interested in the case when A is not invertible

Comment: What do you know about the entries of $A$ and of $b$?

Comment: rational numbers not more

Comment: I don't know that there's a fully general answer to your (original) question. Certainly if $A$ is invertible you can find $x$. If $A$ is the zero matrix, or has more rows than columns, there will exist vectors $b$ such that there is no suitable $x$.